# How to find which visual c++ redistributable is needed by C++ library in VS

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, redistributable

I have VS 2015 solution containing C++ project, so I have a source code of this C++. Im able to compile it.

How to find which visual c++ redistributable is needed for this C++ library? Can I check it in Visual Studio project's properties ?

Comment: What is unclear in this question??

Comment: Everything.  I'd recommend you compile it so it uses the redistributable that matches your VS version.  If this project uses a library you got from somebody else then ask them, not skipping the detail whether or not it is compatible with VS2015 project.

Comment: Are you are building the library from source code? If this is the case, you just use the same redist that comes with visual studio 2015.

Comment: So, if the C++ source code is compiled in VS2015, it needs  Visual C++ Redistibutable 2015 too?

Comment: @Hans, I still dont understand which version of Redistributable  are needed when compiling in VS2015, is it always 2015 or other version can be selected?

Comment: *If the C++ source code is compiled in VS2015, it needs Visual C++ Redistibutable 2015 too?* => Yes

Comment: Can other version be selected? => in general, no. However you can choose to build your code with another toolchain (like VS2008), but you will need to have that version of VS installed as well side by side. What you cannot do, is build with VS2015 compiler and link to a previous version of the VS C++ redist.

Comment: And I fail to see why so many people think this is a bad question... it might be a newbie question, but don't think it is bad per se